# Difference between a device driver and module?

Tags: windows, linux, drivers

### Question:

- What is the difference between a **Device Driver** and a **Module** (or Kernel module) in the context of both **Linux** and **Windows** specifically?

I understand the purpose of a device driver, can you refer to a module interchangeably?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A module is just a bunch of code that can be loaded into Linux. Note that this terminology is specific to Linux; windows typically calls everything a driver, I believe.

In Linux, frequently modules will be device drivers - that is, software that drives some specific piece of hardware (device). Likewise, on Windows, many drivers will be device drivers. However there are drivers and modules that don't drive hardware - for example, some Linux systems may have IPv6 support as a loadable module. Or filesystems such as ISO9660 may be drivers or modules.

Comment: OK, so with regards to Linux, a module is all that is required to 'communicate' with say for instance a graphic card?

Comment: Not necessarily. With graphics cards in particular, the driver is usually split up across one (or more) kernel modules, an X server component, and a GL library that's linked into all client programs.